# C# help with regex pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string.

I have to find a specific part of this string. I would like to use regex.

I need to find destination part in this name*=UTF-8''destination\r\n string. Which would be the good pattern?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find `name*=UTF-8''destination\r\n` you can use something like

```
name\*=(.*)$
```

The part of the string after the `=` would then be in capturing group 1.

if you really want only the `destination` part, its probably more like this

```
name\*=UTF-8''(.*)$
```

`*` is a special character in regex (quantifier for 0 or more occurences) so you need to escape it `\*`

`()` brackets create a capture group (access like `result.Groups[1])`)

`$` is an anchor that matches the end of the line. (your `\r\n`)

```
String Text_A = @"name*=UTF-8''destination
    ";
Regex A = new Regex(@"name\*=UTF-8''(.*)$");
var result = A.Match(Text_A);
Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[1]);
```

but your provided information is a bit sparse, can you explain a bit more and give more context?

Comment: Thanks. This solution is works. Sorry my english is not too good. 
I am working on an Imap/pop3 email client and I was a little problem to get attachment filenames , because it can contains accentuated letters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure which part of your question is the string to be matched, but assuming your string is "name*=UTF-8"destination\r\n", you can use this `Regex` string:

```
@"name\*=UTF-8""(?<destination>.*)\r\n"
```

The "destination" field will be accessible from the Match object, i.e:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"name\*=UTF-8""(?<destination>.*)\r\n");
var match = regex.Match(test);
var destination = match.Groups["destination"].Value;
```

Depending on the context, you may be able to replace some other parts of the match string with more generic regular expression constructs (like `. \w \s` etc)

Cheers,

Simon

Comment: Thanks help. Yes I wanted to find destination part of the string.